# What is the word to describe pseudo-elite people who despite being wealthy have low standards of behavior?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, phrase-requests, idiom-requests, phrase-usage

What I mean is being uncultured, not necessarily evil.

This is *often* the case with people who have recently climbed the socio-economical ladder and newly gained huge wealth in a short amount of time, without developing the **culture and character**. In my native language we have a term to describe these people who lose themselves when they become rich but in English I haven't encountered such a categorization.

Edit: Please stop making false accusations against me. I agree that these examples may be inappropriate but I have no intention of humiliating any race or class in this question. You can read my answers in the comments below this question.

Edit 2: I removed the examples.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124063/discussion-on-question-by-reza-yahyaei-what-is-the-word-to-describe-pseudo-elite).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are probably looking for ***[parvenu](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/parvenu):***

> If you describe someone as a parvenu, you think that although they have acquired wealth or high status they are not very cultured or well-educated.
> [formal, disapproval]

(Collins Dictionary)

Comment: Well _that_ is one I did not know! The Q was worth the answer...

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. This definition pretty much sums up what I mean. I think I made some inappropriate examples but I didn't mean to belittle anyone.

Comment: It sometimes feels like English is a superset of French.

Comment: It is odd that the OP has accepted this answer and explicitly rejected *nouveau riche*, even though they are largely synonymous.

Comment: @jsw29 I didn't reject the "new rich". I said it is less generalized compared to this word and I can't choose two correct answers at the same time because the system doesn't allow me to do such a thing! :)

Comment: @RezaYahyaei, the reason you gave for saying that *nouveau riche* is 'less generalized' was that it 'excludes old rich that also possess poor character'. The same is true of *parvenu*.

Answer (score 8):

I offer

> ALL FUR COATS AND NO KNICKERS
>
> The British- and Irish-English phrase (all) fur coat(s) and no knickers, or no drawers, denotes ostentatious vulgarity in social life, from the literal sense of a fashionably dressed woman whose appearance covers vulgarity.
>
> [Word Histories](https://wordhistories.net/2020/03/12/fur-coat-knickers/)

In Scotland this is more trenchantly expressed as

> “**Fur coat, nae drawers**”
>
> [Word Histories](https://wordhistories.net/2020/03/12/fur-coat-knickers/)

Comment: I don't usually giggle. I giggled.

Comment: @Cascabel Yes I smile at the earthiness here sometimes too. Thanks.

Comment: I'm so sorry if I could choose two correct answers I would choose this one as well. This is also a very interesting phrase.

Comment: Thank you for a kind remark. You chose the most literate one and that is surely the right thing to do. It is often the case that a question has many correct answers.

Answer (score 6):

#### In Australia specifically, "cashed up bogan".

There's a term in Australian dialect of English to describe a similar phenomenon: "cashed up bogan", though it's unused outside of Australia. Quoting the [Wiktionary page](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cashed_up_bogan) on it:

> A person who is unsophisticated or of a lower class background but achieving a high salary, who spends money on flashy or trashy items to fulfil their aspirations of higher social status. The stereotype includes having speech and mannerisms that are considered to denote poor education and uncultured upbringing, which is reflected in their bad taste possessions and lifestyles.

Note that it wouldn't have the connotations of stinginess that the original question asks for, but rather trends towards tacky ostentatious waste.

This term is derived in turn from the word "bogan" which is unique to the Australian dialect, which is used to refer to the uncultured, lower-class members of White Australian society.

Comment: This also reflects what I mean. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

New Money or Nouveau Riche

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nouveau_riche

> Nouveau riche (French: [nuvo ʁiʃ]; French for 'new rich') is a term
> used, usually in a derogatory way, to describe those whose wealth has
> been acquired within their own generation, rather than by familial
> inheritance. The equivalent English term is the "new rich" or "new
> money" (in contrast with "old money"; fr. vieux riche).[1]
> Sociologically, nouveau riche refers to the person who previously had
> belonged to a lower social class and economic stratum (rank) within
> that class; and that the new money, which constitutes his or her
> wealth, allowed upward social mobility and provided the means for
> conspicuous consumption, the buying of goods and services that signal
> membership in an upper class. As a pejorative term, nouveau riche
> affects distinctions of type, the given stratum within a social class;
> hence, among the rich people of a social class, nouveau riche
> describes the vulgarity and ostentation of the newly rich man or woman
> who lacks the worldly experience and the system of values of "old
> money", of inherited wealth, such as the patriciate, the nobility, and
> the gentry.

Comment: This term is the one that is commonly used but it is a bit less generalized (excludes old rich that also possess poor character). Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: @RezaYahyaei Correct. "New Money" was my first thought.. first generation rich that doesn't have the "polish" of old rich. I always think Rodney Dangerfield in Caddyshack https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080487/ as an example of "New Money". I'd say it could include a generation or two down that still haven't gathered the "proper attitudes" yet but you are probably correct in that it would probably be considered to exclude "Old Money" that still has the improper "attitude"

Answer (score 4):

They're called the Clampetts, though I don't know which one has the lowest standard, Jed, Jethro, or maybe it was Granny? Definitely couldn't be gorgeous sweet Elly May... Oh, wait a minute, I got it.... the Kardashians!

In all seriousness though, the problem you have is your question implies you'd like one word to describe two totally separate attributes, and, other than Scrooge, I don't think that's done often in the English language.  A correct answer would depend on the type of behavior the person of wealth portrays. Is the behavior similar to white trailer trash, redneck hillbilly, vulgar, gross and sloppy, mean and evil, etc.
Oncee you decide this then you can create multiple word descriptions such as these: "Pompous money bags" "pretentious aristocrat" "white collared hillbilly" "high-and-mighty well-to-do" " gold diaper baby" "pretentious old hag".... Actually, does that one describe wealth? I don't know I'm just making these up off the top of my head.  " Rich geezer" " capitalist pig" "gold tooth redneck" "Rich B... " (I realized I don't know the rating of the site, lol) " Rich trailer trash" "drunkard with deep pockets"  .... This can go on as far as the imagination. And remember don't forget "Beverly Hillbillies"

Comment: Kardashians definitely fit the bill! lol All the terms you wrote are correct in their respective ways but I needed a general term that was mentioned in one of the answers which I ticked. Thanks for the good laugh tough!